# Unmarshalling without unique node names

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I am stuck trying to figure out how to unmarshall an XML file supplied by IBM Cognos.

The structure does not provide unique names for the different child nodes under the  element but there is a block of metadata that defines the order of the values.

This is a simplified sample of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd"
>
-->
    <metadata>
          <item name="EmployeeID" type="xs:string" length="20"/>
          <item name="firstName" type="xs:string" length="50"/>
          <item name="lastName" type="xs:string" length="50"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>EMP1</value>
            <value>Joe</value>
            <value>Blogs</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>EMP2</value>
            <value>Mary</value>
            <value>Soap</value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

I'm using Spring OXM and Castor for this project and I have no control over the XML format as I am pulling it via a web service from a third party system.

Update : I'm not adverse to swapping out Castor for a different marshalling/unmarshalling library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic of XSLT to the rescue. By running the provided XML through the following XSLT stylesheet I was able to create an XML file that I could then unmarshall correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cognos="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="DataSet">
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()='row']">
        <xsl:variable name="row" select="position()" />
        <xsl:element name="Row">
          <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()='item']">
            <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="@name" />
            <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
            <xsl:element name="{translate($elementName,' ','_')}">
              <xsl:value-of select="//cognos:row[$row]/cognos:value[$index]" />
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformed the XML file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSet>
  <Row>
    <EmployeeID>EMP1</EmployeeID>
    <firstName>Joe</firstname>
    <lastName>Blogs</lastName>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <EmployeeID>EMP2</EmployeeID>
    <firstName>Mary</firstname>
    <lastName>Soap</lastName>
  </Row>
</DataSet>
```